# How to ignore folders name in JCR, searching by XPath

Tags: xpath, jackrabbit, jcr

I want an XPath search expression in JackRabbit so that I can get all subfolders of the third level of folders, from any folders in the first and second level.

I am thinking on something like this: `"/jcr:root/*/*/element(*,nt:folder)"`

but this is wrong, I am getting an empty list, do you guys have anything like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mentioned string `'/jcr:root/*/*/element(*,nt:folder)'` is a valid **XPath** query.
But crossing further in your issue description, you said you want to search all **subfolder** of **3rd level folders**, so maybe you are missing one level depth in your query and that's why you are getting and empty list:

- 3rd level folders are resolved as ***jcr:root -> level 1 -> level 2 -> level 3*** so your query should rather target `/jcr:root/*/*/*` instead of `/jcr:root/*/*`
- subfolder is just resolved as a direct child and you have nothing wrong in your query; `/element(*,nt:folder)`

So maybe the following query would make it `/jcr:root/*/*/*/element(*,nt:folder)`.

Comment: yeah, seems the external party was doing some shenanigans, my code worked for their expecifications, but now it is working properly thanks